# How do I track branches from another repo?

Tags: git, github

How do I track branches from another repo?
I duplicated somebody else's repo and plan to use it as a base for my own changes, but I would like to receive pull request updates when the original repo changes.

Right now I have master and develop in my local repo (these are the ones I would like to track).  Do I delete them, or can I leave them and everything will work out?

I also have a branch that I will use for my changes, derived from their latest source.

I hope this is enough info to help.  My `.git/config` is below.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/me/my-repo/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[remote "other-repo"]
    url = https://github.com/somebody-else/other-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/other-repo/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/other-repo/develop
```

Comment: Maybe I should just change `remote = origin` to `remote = other-repo`?

Comment: Hint: how about having _two_ remotes? Think about it...

Answer (score 0):

You already have two remotes:

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     url = https://github.com/me/my-repo/
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* [remote "other-repo"]
> url = https://github.com/somebody-else/other-repo.git
>     fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/other-repo/master
>     fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/other-repo/develop
> ```

Your second remote, `other-repo`, is almost a single-branch clone, but in fact is a two-branch clone (`master` and `develop` => `other-repo/master` and `other-repo/develop`).  If you replace the last two `fetch` lines with:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/other-repo/*
```

you'll have two full remotes.  This will give you `other-repo/*` remote-tracking names, just as you now have `origin/*` remote-tracking names.

Now, there's no reason *your* branch names have to imitate either of the other remotes' remote-tracking names in your repository.  (There *is* a reason those remote-tracking names have to imitate the branch names in the two remote Git repositories: namely, the `fetch =` lines that have `*` in them.<sup>1</sup>)

That is, suppose *Alice* has branches named `master` and `develop` and so on, that show up in your repository as `alice/*`, and *Bob* has branches `master` and `develop` and so on that all show up as `bob/*`.  You can call *your* (local) branch `malice` when tracking `alice/master`, and `jr-bob-dobbs` when tracking `bob/develop`, if you like.

The same thing goes here: the *upstream* setting of your branch `framboise` can be `other-repo/master`, and the *upstream* of your branch `grand-marnier` can be `origin/master`.  There's no reason you have to use the same branch names they use.  And in fact, if they're using `master` for two different purposes, you *can't* use a single `master` in *your* repository for purposes related to both different purposes.  So, just don't.

---

<sup>1</sup>This provides a second alternative method.  Currently there is only one `*` line, and you could maintain that by replacing all the `fetch =` lines under the second remote to use different *remote-tracking names* for each *branch* name in the remote.  That is, instead of:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/other-repo/master
fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/other-repo/develop
```

you could have:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/other-repo/iron-maiden
fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/other-repo/jethro-tull
```

for instance.  But this way lies madness.